# DB2 Xml framing logics

Tags: db2, db2-luw

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE( 
          XMLELEMENT(
            NAME "row", 
            XMLFOREST(
              A.TITLE AS "title", 
              A.TAG as "tag" ))) 
   FROM ARTICLES A;
```

Expected Result:
  Instead of Mentioned Column name(TITLE ,TAG) ,shall we able to keep '*' (means - select * from Articles)
because my table contains 150 columns.

Comment: Please provide current result and expected result. Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

As @data_henrik said,  your question it not clear ...

But If I got you right,  you want to create a xml doc for all columns from your base table, without having to code all 150 columns in the query.

I don't know a direct way of doing it, but you can do it in a 2 step way.

1st step will be a SELECT statement, that will BUILD your final SELECT based on the columns from your base table..

Let's take DEPARTMENT table from sample db as an example:

```
db2 => select * from department

DEPTNO DEPTNAME                             MGRNO  ADMRDEPT LOCATION
------ ------------------------------------ ------ -------- ----------------
A00    SPIFFY COMPUTER SERVICE DIV.         000010 A00      -
B01    PLANNING                             000020 A00      -
C01    INFORMATION CENTER                   000030 A00      -
...
```

it has 5 columns. The following select will build your final SELECT ...

```
select 
   'SELECT XMLROW( ' || 
    listagg(rtrim(colname) || ' AS "' || lcase(rtrim(colname)) || '"' , ', ') 
   || ' ) FROM DEPARTMENT'  
from syscat.columns 
where tabname = 'DEPARTMENT'

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT XMLROW( ADMRDEPT AS "admrdept", DEPTNAME AS "deptname", DEPTNO AS "deptno", LOCATION AS "location", MGRNO AS "mgrno" ) FROM DEPARTMENT
```

If you execute the resulting SELECT.  it will produce the xml, similar to what you want.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<row><admrdept>A00</admrdept><deptname>SPIFFY COMPUTER SERVICE DIV.</deptname><deptno>A00</deptno><mgrno>000010</mgrno></row>
<row><admrdept>A00</admrdept><deptname>PLANNING</deptname><deptno>B01</deptno><mgrno>000020</mgrno></row>
<row><admrdept>A00</admrdept><deptname>INFORMATION CENTER</deptname><deptno>C01</deptno><mgrno>000030</mgrno></row>
```

**Note:** 
I have used **XMLROW**, for simplicity..  instead of yours `XMLSERIALIZE( XMLELEMEENT( XMLFOREST ...` just as an example..  so you get the idea..